# Using replaceChild to change node

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a node with nodeType = 3, and I want the word "good" to be wrapped by a span.

```
"good morning to you" //node
"<span>good</span> morning to you" //newnode
```

I tried to replace the old node with a new node using the following:

```
newNode = node.cloneNode();
newNode.nodeValue = "<span>good</span> morning to you";
node.parentNode.replaceChild(newNode, node);
```

But this doesn't work at all since I think the node has a nodeType of 3. The span tags are rendered as texts. I'm trying not to use jQuery in this case. Thank you.

Edit 1: To clarify, the node is a childNode of a contentEditable div:

```
<div contenteditable=true>good morning to you</div>
```

"good morning to you" is the childNode of the div, and for this instance a text node.

Comment: the node is not a string, it is an html text node.

Comment: While this doesn't change my solution I would like to mention that `contenteditable` is buggy in most browsers. It's getting better each update though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you're correct, this doesn't work.

Something like this should work:

```
var node = /* the textNode */
var spanEl = document.createElement("span");
var spanTextNode = document.createTextNode();
spanEl.appendChild(spanTextNode);
spanTextNode.nodeValue = "good";
node.nodeValue = " morning to you"
node.parentNode.insertBefore(spanEl, node);
```

As you can this gets a little involved. The DOM API is not the nicest.

You can reduce this a bit to:

```
var node = /* the textNode */
var spanEl = document.createElement("span");
spanEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode("good"));
node.nodeValue = " morning to you"
node.parentNode.insertBefore(spanEl, node);
```

---

You can also just say: *f.ck it* and use innerHTML

```
node.parentNode.innerHTML = "<span>good</span> morning to you";
```

Comment: @Halcyon but if i use contenteditable then text inserting inside span instead parent node

Answer (score 0):

Try disable the contentEditable firstly, replace the content, and then re-enable.

```
//disable contentEditable
ele.contentEditable=false;

//replace
ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.replace(/good/i,'<span>good</span>');

//re-enable
ele.contentEditable=true;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fLSht/1/

Answer (score 0):

So, this may be a bit RAW, but it get's the job done.  What I found out is that you need to wrap the parent node to be some kind of **element node**, then you wrap a part of the text you want in the `<span>` in another node and append it to the parent, and finally you append the rest of the text node to the parent.

```
<script>
    var text1 = document.createTextNode("good");
    var text2 = document.createTextNode(" morning to you");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var parent = document.createElement("div");

    span.appendChild(text1);
    parent.appendChild(span);
    parent.appendChild(text2);

    // use debugger to go into each object
    debugger;
</script>
```

[Here is my example](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/4v2n6/) if you would like to experiment: